# Get count of a database in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get count of all the documents of all the collections in a single MongoDB database.
For now, I am looping through all the collections to get the total count.
Is there any way (MongoDB command/ NodeJS way) of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `db.stats()` and `db.collection.stats()` queries (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) ? Which returns the number of collections and the objects.

Comment: I didn't know about `db.stats`. Although it is showing wrong total count. Even if I include `system.indexes` collection's count!

Comment: But I can use it, Thanks.
Just for info, what values are included in this `count` variable?